# image selected by imagePickerController (PhotoLibrary/Camera) not being displayed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView outlet in my page. I want that to be filled with an image of user's choice. So on click of a button underneath, user can select image from library/camera. 
Till here all s fine. However, once the user selects an image, say from the photo library, it does not display it on the UIIMageView. The following is the code

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
imageView1.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditImage"];
NSLog(@"Image being added to the view");
```

}

The NSLog in console confirms the function call. Any comments on why the image is not being displayed?

Comment: maybe imageView1 is nil?

Comment: but y is it still nil if i am setting the imagView1.image to the image from the picker?

Comment: Not imageView1.image, imageView1. Did you connect in via an IBOutlet in Interface Builder or create it programmatically?

Comment: via Interface Builder.
Do you mean i should instantiate imageView1 in the .m file?
I have defined it in the .h file and synthezise it in the corresponding .m file

Answer (score 0):

Your method should be look like below:

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

{

[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

imageView1.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Dictonary info consist of {

```
UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.image";
UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage = "<UIImage: 0x7c73290>";
UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=70252FFF-1654-49A5-9FEE-5FF19454AE3F&ext=JPG";
```

}

From this you can take image by using key;

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not give the connection to the outlet.
If u have given the connection ,
Implement this Delegate method. In method body use the input parameter "image" like:

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo

{

```
     myImageView.image = image;
```

}

Thats all.